# What does いて do here?

Tags: meaning

ゲームの世界での“欠点”が気になって引っかかっていて、図らずも知恵の輪を解きたいような。

I think this sentence is about the writer getting annoyed and bother by fault in the game but what purpose does いて serve here can't the sentence do just fine without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

引っかかっていて is the て form of 引っかかっている, so your question boils down to the difference between 引っかかる and 引っかかっている. Based on [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/when-is-v%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-the-continuation-of-action-and-when-is-it-the-continuation-of-state?noredirect=1&lq=1), change-in-state verbs like 引っかかる, when conjugated to ている, that is 引っかかっている, emphasizes that he is **currently** in the state brought about by the verb. Without the ている the **present-ness** is not emphasized.